# Gibbs sampler with adaptive linear transformation

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, ergodic

It is a well known fact that linear transformations can dramatically improve the performances of a Gibbs sampler when a ridge-like joint likelihood function occurs.

Can I make an algorithm that detects correlation and makes once in a while corrective linear transformation to the model without losing ergodicity ?

Any references appreciated ! 
Thanks in advance :)